# Jquery page/form steps with toggle?

Tags: jquery

I would like to create a simple form / page step by step without using a plugin already cooked.
To do this I did it this way and it works well.

HTML

```
<div id="p1">
  <input class="goto2" type="button" value="next" />    
</div>

<div id="p2">
  <input class="goto1" type="button" value="prev" />
  <input class="goto3" type="button" value="next" />    
</div>

<div id="p3">
  <input class="goto2" type="button" value="prev" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#p2, #p3 {
   display: none;
}
```

JS

```
$(".goto1").click(function() {
  $('#p2').hide('slow');
  $('#p1').show('slow');
});

$(".goto2").click(function() {
  $('#p1').hide('slow');
  $('#p3').hide('slow');
  $('#p2').show('slow');
});

$(".goto3").click(function() {
  $('#p2').hide('slow');
  $('#p3').show('slow');
});
```

I'd like to do this with a cleaner code, perhaps using the toggle function? Is it possible? Thanks

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5y28h75w/)

Answer (score 2):

I would just check if element has specific class:

```
$("input:button").on("click", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("goto1")) {
        $('#p2').hide('slow');
        $('#p1').show('slow');
    } else if ($(this).hasClass("goto2")) {
        $('#p1, #p3').hide('slow');
        $('#p2').show('slow');
    } else {
        $('#p2').hide('slow');
        $('#p3').show('slow');
    }
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5y28h75w/8/)

Comment: OP states  "perhaps toggle". But anyway if he don't like it he can comment and i will remove it.

Comment: @AlexChar - Yours is cleaner than mine, but you can do it with the toggle function in your opinion? thanks

Comment: @PaoloRossi give me some time please to think about it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
$("input:button").on("click", function () {
var $this = $(this);
var parentId = $this.parent().attr("id");
switch (parentId) {
    case "p1":
        $('.to1').slideToggle();
        break;

    case "p2":
        $this.hasClass("goto1") ? $('.to1').slideToggle() : $('.to2').slideToggle()
        break;

    case "p3":
        $('.to2').slideToggle();
        break;

}
```

});

and for html:

```
<div id="p1" class="to1">
<input class="goto2" type="button" value="next" />
 </div>
 <div id="p2" class="to1 to2">
<input class="goto1" type="button" value="prev" />
<input class="goto3" type="button" value="next" />
 </div>
 <div id="p3" class="to2">
<input class="goto2" type="button" value="prev" />
 </div>
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5y28h75w/9/